# Curl Multi Init Echoing Content from executed pages

Tags: php, curl

I'm having an issue with Curl Multi Init. I'm trying to have it visit multiple sites at the same time and then save their content to variables. Unfortunately, I can't figure out why it seems to be echoing the content of each site. For example, if I tell it to go to two sites, one of the site's content being "hello" and and another being "hey" it would echo "hellohey" -- not sure why this is happening. Here is the code I am using:

```
    <?php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example1.org/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example2.org/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        usleep(100);
    }
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);

?>
```

Comment: This may be exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19639422/541091

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right. You didn't set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true`: return the transfer as a string without passing to `stdout` ([curl-setopt#CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)). Changes:

```
 curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
 curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
```

For saving their content to variables, you should use [curl-multi-getcontent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-getcontent.php).